# Problem improving MySQL. (innodb_log_file_size)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

we are trying to improve the efficiency of our database server.

One of the recommendations of MySQLTunner is rising the innodb_log_file_size to 12 GB. As we see this change could improve significantly the speed and the performance of our queries. The problem came when we increase this parameter more than 1 GB, the service wont start, we delete the logs, stop it cleanly, and still cant start with this parameter above 1 GB.

Someinfo:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G 
innodb_file_per_table   = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 64 
innodb_stats_on_metadata = OFF
innodb_log_file_size = 1G 
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
```

Theres algo enough space in partitions for keeping this log size

Thanks!

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.5, you can't increase the innodb log file size over 4GB total. The `innodb_log_file_size` can only be 4GB / `innodb_log_files_in_group` (which is 2 by default, and there's no benefit to change that). So you can set the log file to a max of 2GB.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size

The max combined size of the log files increased to 512GB in 5.6.3. Again, `innodb_log_file_size` should be the size of *one* log file, so if you use multiple log files, the total cannot exceed 512GB.

I agree with Rick James' answer that increasing the log file size is not a magical solution to make queries run faster. It won't do that.

It's sometimes useful to increase the innodb log file size, if the bottleneck is that you run out of log space faster than dirty pages can be flushed to the tablespace, because you have very high write traffic. That's affected by the rate of writes, not the speed of individual writes.

For most apps, two 2GB log files is more than enough. If it isn't, it's probably time to run multiple MySQL instances, and distribute your write traffic over them as evenly as you can.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to change the log_file_size in that old version.  For the steps, see  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/4103#4103

However, I predict that changing the log_file_size will not help much.  "Performance" usually implies a few slow queries.  Do you have the slowlog turned on?  with a low value of `long_query_time`?  Find the few worst queries; we can probably improve performance by tackling them.  Steps on that: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `innodb_log_file_size` parameter, you need to remove the old log files. Otherwise, Innodb won't start successfully if the existing files do not match the specified size in the config file.

On the other hand, The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of available RAM if you are running InnoDB only.

Comment: We already remove the ib_logfile*, is there any other that we need to remove? The total ram is about 128GB.

Comment: Yeah, here is the jornal after trying to start and fail. https://pastebin.com/J4ZDsEnr

Comment: can you try running mysqld with --verbose flag?

Comment: This is crazy. So if I am running MySQL on a production server and over the years the memory requirements have increased, I can't change this setting without deleting what files again????.   And people who work on MySQL call themselves intelligents????  I can't believe this

Comment: MySql is always surprising I guess :)